# Finding average in .txt file python

Tags: python, text, max, average, minimum

i need to print out average height from a .txt file. How do I write it in an easy way? The .txt file has these numbers:

```
12
14
59
48
45
12
47
65
152
```

this is what i've got so far:

```
import math

text = open(r'stuff.txt').read()
data = []
with open(r'stuff.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        fields = line.split()
        rowdata = map(float, fields)
        data.extend(rowdata)

biggest = min(data)
smallest = max(data)
print(biggest - smallest)
```

Comment: Do you know how to calculate an average, given a list of numbers?

Comment: Why are you reading the whole file into text and never using it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute the average of some numbers, you should sum them up and then divide by the number of numbers:

```
data = []
with open(r'stuff.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        fields = line.split()
        rowdata = map(float, fields)
        data.extend(rowdata)

print(sum(data)/len(data))
```

Comment: Weird that this answer got accepted, as the lines do not have multiple fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [float(ln.rstrip()) for ln in f.readlines()]  # Within 'with' statement.
mean_average = float(sum(data))/len(data) if len(data) > 0 else float('nan')
```

That is the way to calculate the **mean** average, if that is what you meant. Sadly, `math` does not have a function for this. FYI, the `mean_average` line is modified in order to avoid the `ZeroDivisionError` bug that would occur if the `list` had a length of `0`- just in case.

Answer (score 1):

```
# import math -- you don't need this

# text = open(r'stuff.txt').read() not needed.
# data = [] not needed

with open(r'stuff.txt') as f:
    data = [float(line.rstrip()) for line in f]

biggest = min(data)
smallest = max(data)
print(biggest - smallest)
print(sum(data)/len(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Array average can be computed like this:

```
print(sum(data) / len(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple program for finding the average would be the following (if I understand well, your file has one value in each line, if so, it has to be similar to this, else it has to change accordingly):

```
import sys

f = open('stuff.txt', 'rU')    
lines = f.readlines()    
f.close()

size =  len(lines)
sum=0
for line in lines:
    sum = sum + float(line.rstrip())

avg = sum / float(size)    
print avg,
```

Not the best that can be in python but it's quite straight forward I think...

Comment: better with `with` statement

Answer (score 0):

A full, almost-loopless solution combining elements of other answers here:

```
with open('stuff.txt','r') as f:
    data = [float(line.rstrip()) for line in f.readlines()]
    f.close()
mean = float(sum(data))/len(data) if len(data) > 0 else float('nan')
```

and you don't need to prepend, append, enclose or import anything else.